# Delaying the search function in keypress actions

Tags: c#, search, timer, delay

I'm trying to delay an action on a textbox. I want to search a large quantity of text for a word. Now I do this with the "textchanged" event. The problem here is, when he reaches a word of more then 3 letters (I've prevented 0-2 wordsearches) the process becomes intensive.

Question: 
What are my possibilities here?

- ex: Putting a timer on the textchanged-event? If so, how do I do this?

Code:

```
private void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 // delay here
 dosearch(searchbox.text);
}
```

Comment: Is this WPF or Silverlight?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

(Re)start a dispatcher timer every time a key is pressed, and do the search when the timer elapses. Around 200-300 ms delay is usually pretty good.

```
private DispatcherTimer _searchTimer;

// Initialize timer in constructor with 200 ms delay and register tick event.

private void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _searchTimer.Stop();
    _searchTimer.Start();
}

private void OnSearchTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _searchTimer.Stop()
    Search(searchBox.Text);
}

private void Search(string searchTxt)
{
    // Do search
}
```

UPDATE:
To improve the responsiveness (the above example will lock the UI while searching because the dispatcher timer callback runs on the UI thread), you can execute the search in a separate Task. When the search completes you need to ensure that the result is not stale (that the user has not modified the search text while searching):

```
private void Search(string searchText)
{
    Task.Run(() =>
        {
            // Execute search

            Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                if (searchText == searchBox.Text)
                {
                    // Result is good
                }
            });
    });
}
```

Comment: 200ms delay means a user types 300 characters per minute. Not every user types as fast as that. I'd say make it 500ms at least. Otherwise +1

Comment: True, it's a balance between allowing slow typers, and also keeping it very responsive.

Comment: Nicely, just implemented this solution and I must say: I'm a fast typer and this is good even for me.

Comment: Why not executing the search only if search text hasn't changed?

Comment: @sinsedrix imagine that the user is typing off a piece of paper. He might need to look at the paper, taking longer than the 300-500 ms. At this point the search will kick off, even though the user didn’t actually finish typing. When the search returns, the user has in the mean time typed the remaining text, and a second search has been launched. Now we have two simultaneous search queries running, and we need to make sure we only use the result from the one matching the final search string.

Comment: @sondergard ok very clever and powerful